# Where was the last episode of BSG filmed?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

In Daybreak Part 2, the crew of the Battlestar Galactica land on a planet which William Adama calls "Earth" because they "deserved it". *Where is this part of the show filmed?*

From what I have found through searching, it appears to be in **Kamloops, British Columbia, Canada** but I am having trouble nailing down the exact location

Comment: Filmed on location in space.

Comment: Of course! How could I be so dumb to ask! tsk tsk

Comment: Most likely BC somewhere as most of SciFi's shows are filmed out of studios in Vancouver.

Comment: It sounds like you have it narrowed down pretty well, all things considered. Are you looking for GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that it was filmed in the city of Kamloops in British Columbia, but it looks like that episode was filmed on private land. [Here is a blog entry](http://www.battlestarlocations.com/1/post/2011/08/daybreak-iii.html) by people who visited the location. They mention a "guide". Perhaps a nice [email to them](http://www.battlestarlocations.com/about-us.html) can get you more details (at least details about who the guide was).